# Remove Spacy downloaded model

Tags: python, pip, nlp, spacy

After downloading and linking a spacy model (en large) by:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

which is around 850 Mb of data.

How can it find and delete the data (downloaded model) on my mac to free some space?

```
Spacy: 2.0.18  
Python: 3.6.9  
en_core_web_lg: 2.0.0
```

Comment: pip uninstall en-core-web-lg

Answer (score 12):

The `download` command will install the model via `pip`, place the package in your `site-packages`. So, the data should be inside the `spacy` directory inside your python's `site-packages`.
Try to check some where like `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/en_core_web_sm`

Comment: To add to this: If they *actually* ran `spacy.en.download` instead of `spacy download en` (and it's not a typo), this would indicate that they're using spaCy v1.6 or lower, before the models as Python packages were introduced. In this case, the model would have been installed in the `spacy/data` directory, also in the site packages. An easy way to find that location is to run `python -c "import spacy; print(spacy.__file__)"`.